# java.lang.String - facebook ad

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-ads-api

I am using facebook ads. I wanted to put native ad to my react native expo app, but i got error. When i put simple banner all is ok. It gives me this error:
Uncaught Error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
I tried to import like this:
import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';
but it gave me this error:
 Unable to resolve "@unimodules/core" from "node_modules/expo-ads-facebook/build/withNativeAd.js"

What am i doing wrong?

```html
// pageScreen.js
import React from 'react';

import { FacebookAds } from 'expo'

import AdScreenFacebook from './AdScreenFacebook'

class AdScreen extends React.Component {
  render () {
          return (

             <AdScreenFacebook adsManager={adsManager} adChoicePosition="topLeft" expandable={false} />

          );
      }

 }

// AdScreenFacebook.js

import React from 'react';

import { FacebookAds } from 'expo'
const { AdIconView, AdMediaView } = FacebookAds;

const adsManager = new FacebookAds.NativeAdsManager("2272791379702600_2272795453035526", "1");

class AdScreenFacebook extends React.Component {
  render () {
          return (
      <View>
        <AdMediaView />
        <AdTriggerView>
          <Text>{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
        </AdTriggerView>
      </View>
    );
      }

 }


export default FacebookAds.withNativeAd(AdScreenFacebook);







  export default createStackNavigator(
    {
      Main: {
        screen: AdScreen,
      },
      AdScreenFacebook: {
        screen: AdScreenFacebook,
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Main',
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks from the number 1 in the NativeAdsManager function. You are currently passing that function the number 1 as a string instead of as a number.

```
// AdScreenFacebook.js

const adsManager = new FacebookAds.NativeAdsManager("2272791379702600_2272795453035526", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

With **SDK 33**, we’re **deprecating imports of most modules from the `expo package`**. This means that in a future release, you won’t be able to write, for example, `import { FacebookAds } from 'expo';`. Rather, you’ll need to install the individual packages for each module you use and import from them instead.

You can use the new `expo install` command to install modules; this command is a wrapper around `npm install/yarn add` that automatically installs a module version compatible with your SDK version. For example, for the **`FacebookAds module`**, you would run `expo install expo-ads-facebook` and then use `import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';`. This change paves the way for tree-shaking and smaller JavaScript bundles. It also makes moving between the managed and bare workflows simpler.

If you want to use a Expo module such as a question, [**install it**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-codemod) and set it up.

For [managed](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#managed-workflow) apps, you'll need to run `expo install expo-ads-facebook`. To use it in a [bare](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow) React Native app, follow its [installation instructions](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-ads-facebook).

**Usage**

```js
import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';
const { AdTriggerView, AdMediaView } = FacebookAds;

class AdComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <AdMediaView />
        <AdTriggerView>
          <Text>{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
        </AdTriggerView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default FacebookAds.withNativeAd(AdComponent);
```